# How to conserve memory in Java?

Tags: java

Writing a java program is not a big deal .but how to make that program more efficient means less memory consuming, re usability,can any one explain ..how to do that in java ...

Comment: entire books have been written on this topic...

Answer (score 3):

Read the below two books

1. [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)
2. [Clean code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

Answer (score 1):

Travis is right, but here are some quick things you can do

Use final, static, and private modifiers when ever possible. 
Keep your resources in mind, and free variables when ever possible

{
//Variables in between brackets go away at the end, so incase temporary variables in brackets
}

Analysis, re-analysis your algorithm, try to make it mulit-threaded.

If you still can't get the performance you want, go for C!

Answer (score 0):

You make a program consume less memory by reducing either the size or the number of objects it creates (or both). A heap profiler like VisualVM is the best tool to find out where to start.